# How to Include Parentheses in Spring JPA Specification's WHERE Clause

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

How can I use Spring JPA Specification for the WHERE condition in the following ways:

```
Where cond1 AND (cond2 OR cond3)
```

or

```
Where (cond1 AND cond2) OR cond3.
```

I have defined the Specification code as follows for the second case:

```
Specification<DocRecord> updatedAtAndCountGTZeroSpec = new Specification<DocRecord>() {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DocRecord> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.or(
            (cb.and(
                cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("updatedAt"), new Timestamp(now.getTimeInMillis())),
                cb.lessThan(root.get("attemptCount"), 3)
            )),
            (cb.equal(root.get("attemptCount"), 0))
        );
    }
};
```

However, the generated query should be:

```
WHERE docrecord0_.updated_at < ? AND (docrecord0_.attempt_count < 3 OR docrecord0_.attempt_count = 0)
```

OR

```
WHERE (docrecord0_.updated_at < ? AND docrecord0_.attempt_count < 3) OR docrecord0_.attempt_count = 0
```

But what I get on the console is:

```
WHERE docrecord0_.updated_at < ? AND docrecord0_.attempt_count < 3 OR docrecord0_.attempt_count = 0
```

It seems that the parenthesis are not included in the generated query. How can I modify the Specification code to achieve the desired behavior and include the parenthesis in the generated SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is below.

**AND** has a precedence over **OR** condition so the parenthesis will be redundent in your case
`(cb.or(cb.and(p1,p2),p3)`.
It will first do the AND and then perform the OR.

If you will reverse the condition like this
`(cb.and(cb.or(p1,p2),p3)` then it is going to add the appropriate parenthesis because it first need to do the OR then perform the AND.